# Compare 2 ISO 8601 timestamps and output seconds/minutes difference

Tags: javascript

I need to write JavaScript that's going to allow me to compare two ISO timestamps and then print out the difference between them, for example: "32 seconds".

Below is a function I found on Stack Overflow, it turns an ordinary date into an ISO formatted one. So, that's the first thing out the way, getting the current time in ISO format.

The next thing I need to do is get another ISO timestamp to compare it with, well, I have that stored in an object. It can be accessed like this: marker.timestamp (as shown in the code below). Now I need to compare those two two timestamps and work out the difference between them. If it's < 60 seconds, it should output in seconds, if it's > 60 seconds, it should output 1 minute and 12 seconds ago for example.

Thanks!

```
function ISODateString(d){
 function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
 return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCMonth()+1)+'-'
      + pad(d.getUTCDate())+'T'
      + pad(d.getUTCHours())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+':'
      + pad(d.getUTCSeconds())+'Z'}

var date = new Date();
var currentISODateTime = ISODateString(date);
var ISODateTimeToCompareWith = marker.timestamp;

// Now how do I compare them?
```

Comment: So you want to compare `currentISODateTime` with `ISODateTimeToCompareWith` and they are both in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: @Campari Yes, exactly that, then output the difference between them. They are both in ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Comparing two dates is as simple as

```
var differenceInMs = dateNewer - dateOlder;
```

So, convert the timestamps back into *Date* instances

```
var d1 = new Date('2013-08-02T10:09:08Z'), // 10:09 to
    d2 = new Date('2013-08-02T10:20:08Z'); // 10:20 is 11 mins
```

Get the difference

```
var diff = d2 - d1;
```

Format this as desired

```
if (diff > 60e3) console.log(
    Math.floor(diff / 60e3), 'minutes ago'
);
else console.log(
    Math.floor(diff / 1e3), 'seconds ago'
);
// 11 minutes ago
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the 'e3' bit mean after the numbers?

Comment: Oh I see, I take it it was just a shortcut for 60k. :P

Comment: Does this take into account any differences in timezone, though?

Comment: For differences over multiple timezones you would need to provide one when instantiating the date, or have already your dates converted to a single timezone.

Comment: When I'm storing the time from database to the variable then the `diff` is coming out to be `NAN`

Comment: Sometimes typescript reject LHS arithmetic operation types. so use valueOf() function
**const diff = d2.valueOf() - d1.valueOf();**

Answer (score 2):

I would just store the Date object as part of your ISODate class.  You can just do the string conversion when you need to display it, say in a `toString` method.  That way you can just use very simple logic with the Date class to determine the difference between two ISODates:

```
var difference = ISODate.date - ISODateToCompare.date;
if (difference > 60000) {
  // display minutes and seconds
} else {
  // display seconds
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend getting the time in seconds from both timestamps, like this:

```
// currentISODateTime and ISODateTimeToCompareWith are ISO 8601 strings as defined in the original post
var firstDate = new Date(currentISODateTime),
    secondDate = new Date(ISODateTimeToCompareWith),
    firstDateInSeconds = firstDate.getTime() / 1000,
    secondDateInSeconds = secondDate.getTime() / 1000,
    difference = Math.abs(firstDateInSeconds - secondDateInSeconds);
```

And then working with the `difference`. For example:

```
if (difference < 60) {
    alert(difference + ' seconds');
} else if (difference < 3600) {
    alert(Math.floor(difference / 60) + ' minutes');
} else {
    alert(Math.floor(difference / 3600) + ' hours');
}
```

**Important: I used `Math.abs` to compare the dates in seconds to obtain the absolute difference between them, regardless of which is earlier.**

Comment: I found that you should divide the `(new Date(ISO)).getTime()` by 1000 instead of multiply by 1000 to achieve the value in seconds.

Comment: This is not working if the date is stored to the variable from the database.